# Selecting 7th value of a column

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe

```
 Date   Countries   Confirmed   Deaths  Recovered
 01/02/2020 United Kingdom  2   0   0
 02/02/2020 United Kingdom  2   0   0
 03/02/2020 United Kingdom  8   0   0
 04/02/2020 United Kingdom  8   0   0
 05/02/2020 United Kingdom  9   0   0
 06/02/2020 United Kingdom  9   0   0
 07/02/2020 United Kingdom  9   0   0
 08/02/2020 United Kingdom  13  0   0
 09/02/2020 United Kingdom  14  0   0
 10/02/2020 United Kingdom  14  0   0
 11/02/2020 United Kingdom  15  0   0
 12/02/2020 United Kingdom  16  0   1
 13/02/2020 United Kingdom  17  0   1
 14/02/2020 United Kingdom  18  0   1
 15/02/2020 United Kingdom  18  0   1
 16/02/2020 United Kingdom  18  0   8
 17/02/2020 United Kingdom  19  0   8
 18/02/2020 United Kingdom  19  0   8
 19/02/2020 United Kingdom  20  0   8
 20/02/2020 United Kingdom  22  0   8
 21/02/2020 United Kingdom  23  0   8
 22/02/2020 United Kingdom  23  0   8
```

I want to select only the 7th values of the numeric columns along with the date & country.How can this be done ?

For example

```
07/02/2020  United Kingdom  9   0   0
13/02/2020  United Kingdom  17  0   1
20/02/2020  United Kingdom  22  0   8
```

Can someone help ?

Comment: Loop over the rows and use a modulo operator to identify the row. If row_number mod 7 = 0 : select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use iloc, which takes a row - column slice, both based on integer position and follows python syntax.
Here is example of slicing rows and keeping all the columns.

```
df.iloc[6::7, :])
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it the following way :

```
UK
start = 0
step = 7
selection = [x for x in range(start,len(UK),step) ]
new_df = UK.iloc[selection,:]
new_df
```

Comment: this is much more complex than it needs to be, you can just do `UK[start::step]`